# Getting the "latest" field in a set to serialize in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

My current serializer looks like so:

```
class BareboneEntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = (
            'id', 'label', 'related_yid_count', 'description',
        )
```

There is one set: `entityclassification_set` Now, in my other serializer I have it like so:

```
entityclassification_set = EntityClassificationSerializer(many=True)
```

But after some time, I realized I only need the "latest" or the last element in the set, how can I add this field to the serializer? Is adding a property the only way to go about this? Or is there another way to do it?

Right now I can do this

```
@property
def classification(self):
    return EntityClassification.objects.filter(entity=self).latest()
```

But is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

```
entities = Entity.objects.order_by('-id')[:5]
entityclassification_set = EntityClassificationSerializer(entities, many=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't what I need. I need the latest EntityClassification for each entity instead of all EntityClassification for the last 5 entities.